# probability of a positive random variable larger than a sequence tending to 0

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ such that $X > 0$. The distribution of $X$ is not known. Let $\{ a_k \}_{k = 1}^\infty$ be a sequence such that $a_k \downarrow 0 $.

Intuitively $P[ X > a_k ] \rightarrow 1$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$. I am wondering if the following proof is correct, and/or if there is an easier/better way to do this?

*Proof*: Let $f_k(\omega) = I(X(\omega) > a_k)$, where $I(A)$ is the indicator function of set $A$.

Then clearly $0 \le f_k(\omega) \le f_{k + 1}(\omega)$. The limit of $f_k$ is $I(X(\omega) > 0)$. Then Lebesgue's monotone convergence theorem would give the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is correct.

However, I would say that applying the monotone convergence theorem is kind of overkill. What you are really using is that the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ is continuous from above (i.e. that $A_k \downarrow A$ implies $\mathbb{P}(A_k) \to \mathbb{P}(A)$.) Simply note that

$$A_k := \{X>a_k\} \downarrow \{X>0\}$$

and therefore, by the continuity of the measure,

$$1 = \mathbb{P}(X>0) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(X>a_k).$$

Comment: Thank you. I knew I was overthinking on the matter but was not able to find a better way.

Comment: @cly31107 You are welcome.